# How do I allow users to combine a external string and a regex capture value?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

### Environment:

C# .Net 4.0, VS2010.

### Background:

I have an application that reads data over the network and converts that to xml. This xml data is then used by other downstream user applications for various purposes.

Previously, some users had requested to add a setting to allow them to replace certain strings in the data by their custom strings using a regex match. This was then built into the application

### Problem:

Now there is a new request where users not only want to use a custom string but they also want to combine it with a part of the match that they get from the regular expression.

I know that we can use matches, groups and captures to do this, but how do I allow it to be configured from settings?

Currently I use a class like below to manage the custom labels and their regexes

```
[SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
public class CustomSettingsGroup
{
    [SettingsSerializeAs(SettingsSerializeAs.Xml)]
    public class CustomSetting
    {
        public string CustomLabel { get; set; }
        public string RegularExpression { get; set; }
    }

    public List<CustomSetting> CustomSettingCollection { get; set; }
}
```

The current logic in the app simply goes over all the regexes for the input, stops at the   1st match, and uses the label for that regex in the input.

Comment: If you are replacing the entire match no problem, same with appending to the match data. If you have to repace the entire match with a combination partial match plus label, regex's will have to be custom as well as the replacement, and stored probably the same way you store the label/regex now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I pretty much agree with Jacob's idea, I just want to give a more detailed answer. I've done similar configs in the past many times, it's easy.

There is one important thing: In case of regex group capturing it is a very good practice to support regex group names! For example in case of this regex:

```
 @"^blahblah(?<groupname>\d+)blahblah$"
```

The specified group can be accessed as either group index 1 or as group name "groupname". This results in much easier and readable configuration. Not to mention that modifying an existing regex with many groups can screw up existing indexes and with group names this isn't a problem.

What you still need is a formatter function that receives a format string as a parameter along with a regex match object (that contains the group values). This is how I usually define the format of the format string:

- `$$` in the format string translates to a single `$` in the formatted string
- `$0`, `$1`, ... `$N` and `${0}`, `${1}`, ... `${N}` translates to the value of the regex group at the specified index
- `$groupname` and `${groupname}` translates to the value of the regex group with the specified name

I usually handle/accept the `${xyz}` form too in the format string because without this you can not handle situations like the following format string: `Score: ${score}000`
Without the `{` and `}` the format string would be `Score: $score000` so you would parse the group name from the format string as `score000`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this `CustomLabel` could allow for positional placeholders, like `$1` and `$2`, which would represent a substitution of a regular expression capture. This is a fairly typical thing to do with regex tools. When you generate the output, you could do a regex replace on anything of the form `\$(\d+)` with the capture group at the desired position.